# Get same column by name using same code for two differently structured lists

Tags: r, list

I have two differently structured lists. And in a function I want to get a column that has the same name in both lists. Is there a generic way to deal with this?

```
  list_1_1_1 <- list(list(list(tibble::tibble("a" = c(1, 2), "b"=c(3, 4))), list("a"=c(1, 2))))
  list_1_1_1
  # Call column called b
  list_1_1_1[[1]][[1]][[1]]$b

  
  list_1_1 <- list(list(tibble::tibble("a" = c(1, 2), "b"=c(3, 4))), list("a"=c(1, 2)))
  list_1_1
  # Call column called b
  list_1_1[[1]][[1]]$b
```

I would like to get column called b, with the same line of code that works in the two different situations/examples, is that possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question; this is just what that column happened to be called in this example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```
foo <- function(l, pattern) {
  u <- unlist(l)
  unname(u[grep(pattern, names(u))])
}

foo(list_1_1_1, "b")
# 3 4

foo(list_1_1, "b")
# 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

With an external package, we can do this out-of-the-box with `rrapply` (an extension of base-`rapply` to recurse through a nested list):

```r
library(rrapply)

rrapply(list_1_1_1, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "b", how = "flatten")
#> $b
#> [1] 3 4
rrapply(list_1_1, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "b", how = "flatten")
#> $b
#> [1] 3 4
```

The `condition` argument decides which list elements (data.frame columns in this case) to return and the `.xname` argument evaluates to the name of the list element (i.e. the column name) under evaluation.

The advantage with respect to a function that `grep`s elements based on the names constructed by `unlist` is that we can avoid any unexpected behavior:

```r
foo <- function(l, pattern) {
  u <- unlist(l)
  unname(u[grep(pattern, names(u))])
}

## there are two 'a' columns, which are collapsed after unlisting the list
foo(list_1_1_1, "a")
#> [1] 1 2 1 2
## here the individual columns are still present
rrapply(list_1_1_1, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "a", how = "flatten")
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2

## no 'a1' column is present in the data, but new names are assigned by unlist
foo(list_1_1_1, "a1")
#> [1] 1 1
## here no column is returned as expected
rrapply(list_1_1_1, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "a1", how = "flatten")
#> named list()
```